# How to disable hover state on active link

Tags: html, css

there is a double red line on hover state on my active link (another red line appears on dropdown menu. How to fix this. Also when i moving on dpopdown menu active state dissapears.
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uj5k5ecq/)

```
Thank you.
Have a nice day.

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/uj5k5ecq/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a new class `.jqueryslidemenu ul li a.active:hover` and giving it a `border-bottom:0;` should do it, but there's something that I'm trying to figuring out is why the drop down is not filling that 5px removed from the border-bottom ... until now I have this:

```
.jqueryslidemenu ul li a.active:hover {
    border-bottom:0;
}
```

**======== Update ==========**

I figured it out, it's somehere in your jquery code (probably in your file `jqueryslidemenu.js`) that has a static position for your dropdown of `top:56px;` by giving a new `top` value for `.jqueryslidemenu ul li ul` through your css like this it will fix this issue

```
.jqueryslidemenu ul li ul {
    top: 51px !important;
}
```

Online **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/uj5k5ecq/4/)**
but perhaps you should find that value and change it there tho, where this `top:56px;` is being created

Comment: There is a problem with this solution, also.

Comment: You're welcome @LjubisaTrajkov . marking my answer as correct or giving it a rating is much appreciated :)

Comment: But i don't know how to do that, i'm new to this website.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to remove the on hover underline by adding this to your CSS:

`#nav a:hover{text-decoration:none;}`

Another option is to remove the red border when you hover over a dropdown by removing `border-top: 5px solid #eb2629;`.  Example below:

```
.jqueryslidemenu ul li ul {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
margin-left: -1px;  
border-top: 5px solid #eb2629; /** REMOVE THIS LINE **/
display: block;
visibility: hidden;
background: #000;
z-index: 99999;
}
```

A third option is to remove the active red border when you hover over the link itself:

```
.jqueryslidemenu ul li a.active {
border-bottom: 5px solid #eb2629; /** REMOVE THIS LINE **/
color: #eb2629; 
}
```

Comment: You'll need to be more specific with your question then.  I gave three possible solutions to three different red lines in your code.  Can you provide a screenshot of what you are trying to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

View [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uj5k5ecq/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but I think you might mean something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/uj5k5ecq/3/

```
#nav {
float: right;
margin-top: 70px;
position: relative;
}
.jqueryslidemenu ul {
z-index:9999999;
}
.jqueryslidemenu ul li {
position: relative;
float: left;
list-style:none;
}
.jqueryslidemenu ul li a {
font-weight: normal;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 13px;
margin-top: 18px;
padding: 0px 20px 15px;
display: block;
text-decoration:none;
color:#000;
}
.jqueryslidemenu ul li a:hover {
border-bottom: 5px solid #eb2629;
color: #eb2629;
}
.jqueryslidemenu ul li a.active {
}
.jqueryslidemenu ul li ul {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
margin-left: -1px;
border-top: 5px solid #eb2629;
display: block;
visibility: hidden;
background: #000;
z-index: 99999;
}
/*Sub level menu list items (undo style from Top level List Items)*/
.jqueryslidemenu ul li ul li {
float: none;
font-size:12px;
width: 160px;
text-transform: none;
background-color: #000;
}
.jqueryslidemenu ul li ul li a {
margin: 0px;
color:#fff;
padding: 10px 20px 10px;
border-bottom: none;
text-transform: none;
}
.jqueryslidemenu ul li ul li a:hover {
background:#232323;
color: #FFF;
border-bottom: none;
text-transform: none;
}
```